# SQL Server 2008 - Versions Installed Size

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

Is there a significant difference in the size on disk between the different versions of SQL Server 2008?

I am setting up a test environment on my laptop and I was wondering if there is any reason not to install the enterprise version of SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The size difference among the SQL versions is no big deal. If you really want to test all the features then you really want to install the enterprise version (or the Developer version).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  (Why did you not make this an answer instead of a comment?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be any difference between Standard/Enterprise. You will see a difference depending on optional features that you do or don't install (Analysis or Reporting services, for example).